# Is it an error to use "it" to refer to two different things in one compound sentence?

Tags: usage, pronouns

An example:

> Alice: I've been to a vet. My **cat** has a *tumor*.
>
> Bob: Don't worry. If *it*'s not malignant, **it** will be fine.

> Carmen: Are you sure this **cake** *recipe* is correct.
>
> Daniel: My grandmother gave *it* to me, I'm sure **it** will taste great.

Comment: Why close? Why not explain?

Comment: Everything like this is context related and whether the speakers know the context. It is not grammar.

Comment: @Lambie this wasn't a question about grammar but about writing style, the sort of things you would lose points for when writing a short story for an English class (for English natives). I'm not sure why it was moved from english to ell.

Comment: It was moved because it is too obvious. I know it isn't about grammar. That's what I said. Actually, it will be fine may not only refer to the cat, it can also mean: the situation [for the cat] will be fine and would be a dummy pronoun.

Comment: And it seems to me you have good enough English to know that: If it's not malignant, it will be fine. would be better as: If it's not malignant, the cat will be fine.

Comment: @Lambie maybe this specific example may be better with "cat" instead of "it" but I wouldn't be asking if I knew the answer. I wrote a comment with double "it" referring to two different nouns and there didn't seem to be anything wrong with it but I changed it anyway. The changed version was unambiguous but unnatural. This is why I asked which one is stylistically preferred.

Comment: If you translate this into your language, wouldn't you have the same problem??

Comment: @Lambie Maybe, but it's very hard to find an example like this, since in many cases both subjects should be omitted, in most at least the first subject is omitted and in the rest, the grammatical case will be different. The one example I managed to find doesn't translate well, because it sounds correct in Polish but not in English: "If he doesn't start thinking with whom (he) associates, he will kill him." In Polish the first pronoun should be omitted but is added to emphasize the frustration with the subject (like yelling "Benjamin" v. "Ben"). Unlike "he", they have different functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context is everything. The simple answer to this question is *no*, it's not *always* and automatically an error to use the same pronoun word twice in one sentence to refer to different antecedents. But you have to check whether your meaning is clear or not and avoid creating ["garden-path sentences"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence) or ambiguity. For instance: "The cat is in the garden. It's sad because it's wet." Well, it's pretty clear that the garden isn't sad, but it's not quite clear whether the cat is dismayed because it is wet itself, or simply because the garden is.

The meaning is clear enough in the examples you gave, even if the antecedent isn't *totally* clear. In "If it's not malignant, **it** will be fine," the second *it* could refer to the cat, or also to a sort of "universal *it*," meaning "this situation in general will be fine." In fact, this could also be an interpretation of my cat/garden sentence, since "it's wet" can be a statement about the weather. Both with the vet and the garden, these interpretations don't really significantly change the outcome or the general meaning, so they're not problematic. Similarly, in the cake-recipe conversation, Carmen could even have left the word "cake" out of her question and the response would make sense because it's understood and implied.

Comment: Oh look, context is everything. :)

Comment: @Lambie Maybe I should just make it my username!

Comment: Sounds good to me, and I can be: Resistance is futile. [haha]

Answer (score -4):

It refers to one noun. By making it a plural possessive (it's) you are referring to an object belonging to the noun. If your sentence includes two nouns that may be mentioned as "it", be more clear.

Comment: _it's_ isn't plural or possessive.